# Show all infowindows open

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have custom infowindows float above markers, however I noticed that only one marker can be opened at any one time. Is there a workaround to this?

Here's the code I have produced at the moment:

```
downloadUrl("AllActivityxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
        );

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html = "<b>" + point + "</b>hello <br/>" + type;
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

        markersArray.push(marker);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);        


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(html); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
});
```

And when you check [this map](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php), notice that I cannot open more than 2 infowindows at once. Why is that?

Comment: Opposite situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567280/google-api-v3-multiple-infowindows-plus-close-on-click

Answer (score 2):

There is no limitation implicit to the Google Maps API v3 that makes only one InfowWindow available at a time.  You need to write your code to do that. If you want an InfoWindow for each marker, make one.

Some thing like (not tested):

```
function createMarker(latlng, html) {
   var contentString = html;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, here's the [code I added](http://jsfiddle.net/drCyf/), however look at the result [here](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php). When I click on any one marker, it opens an additional info window on another marker. Also, I cannot open more than 2 markers at any one point. Why is that?

Comment: You need function closure.  You took out the function.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to add the closure in the jsfiddle. I [updated it now](http://jsfiddle.net/drCyf/1/), however that should not be the issue as the code on the site had it from the start.

Comment: There is no function closure in the code on the site either.  The reason that site only is working the way it is is because that is the way the code is written.  There is one global infoWindow, and another created inside one of xml processing loops.  You didn't understand the difference between my answer and the code on your page.

Comment: Hmm, let me have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob. I thought by function closure, you meant that I should _close up_ function `downloadUrl("AllActivityxml.php", function(data) {`, Also, doesn't the script create a separate marker as it goes through each xml line as quoted here? `for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {`. I will look into the code and try to fix it up!

Comment: Okay, I [updated the code](http://jsfiddle.net/drCyf/3/), however the infowindow [now pops up on a marker completely different from the one I click on](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php). Also, I still can't get multiple markers to run at once.

Comment: For which function specifically? `window.onload = function(){` ? Or `downloadUrl("eventsxml.php", function(data) {` ?

Comment: The function in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean the last `}'? Because I would have to then add `function createMarker(latlng, html) {` at the beggining, which results in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/drCyf/4/) and now [none markers are showing](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php).

Comment: I don't understand that at all. How can foo be 321 the first time when it's defined as 123?.... to be honest I don't understand it at all :(... I know it adds 1 at the end, so it should be 322 the second time, but if the function is re-run, shouldn't `var foo=123;` replace it?

Comment: Javascript function closure is a complicated topic, if you didn't understand Mike's explanation, then do some research on the web. It is not really a topic for discussion in the comments on StackOverflow.