# google maps auto open infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem getting info windows on my google map to auto open I have followed a tutorial here...

https://www.taniarascia.com/google-maps-apis-for-multiple-locations/

Everything is working but I require that the 3 info windows on my map open on page load so visitors see them without having to click the markers.

I have tried several solutions I found here..

[Google maps-api v3 InfoWindow automatically open on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342994/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-automatically-open-on-page-load)

but cant get any of them to work.

```js
function initMap() {
 
 var scorrier = {
  info: '<center><img src="assets/images/ge-logo-300px.jpg"><br><br>\
     <strong>The Great Estate</strong><br>\
     Scorrier House<br>Cornwall, TR16 5AU<br>\
     <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Bristol/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.8495256,-5.0243318,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4871836681b3d861:0x8ee4b22e4b9ad71f!2m2!1d-2.58791!2d51.454513!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></center></strong>',
  lat: 50.2501818,
  long: -5.1924054
 };

 var redruth = {
  info: '<strong>Redruth Train Station</strong><br>\
     Redruth<br>Cornwall, TR15 2AB<br>\
     <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/TR15+2AB,+Station+Rd,+Redruth/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.2428949,-5.2183829,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b1f5fb5f4a7ed:0xfa94523df7169fe6!2m2!1d-5.2258756!2d50.2332886!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818?shorturl=1" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></strong>',
  lat: 50.233210,
  long: -5.225936
 };

 var truro = {
  info: '<strong>Truro Train Station</strong><br>\r\
     Station Road, Truro<br> Cornwall, TR1 3HH<br>\
     <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Truro,+Station+Road,+Truro,+Cornwall+TR1+3HH/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.2646882,-5.1661898,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b17b40079af5d:0x9752f63a0a1484f8!2m2!1d-5.0641465!2d50.2640872!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818?shorturl=1" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></strong>',
  lat: 50.264087,
  long: -5.064146
 };

 var locations = [
      [scorrier.info, scorrier.lat, scorrier.long, 0],
      [redruth.info, redruth.lat, redruth.long, 1],
      [truro.info, truro.lat, truro.long, 2],
    ];

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 13,
  scrollwheel: false,
  gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2501818, -5.1924054),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

 var marker, i;

 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
   map: map
  });
  
  
  /* Not sure how to trigger all info windows to open on page load not click????
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  */

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
   return function () {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
  })(marker, i));
  
  
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
 <script src="assets/js/map.js"></script>
  <script async defer 
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?MYKEYISHERE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Related question (closed): [Show all infowindows open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824077/show-all-infowindows-open)

If you want to have more than one InfoWindow open at a time you need to create one for each marker (assuming you want them open on *all* the markers, if you only ever want three, then only create three).

[image]

**code snippet using a `createMarker` function to get closure on the marker/infowindow:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {

    var scorrier = {
      info: '<center><img src="assets/images/ge-logo-300px.jpg"><br><br>\
                    <strong>The Great Estate</strong><br>\
                    Scorrier House<br>Cornwall, TR16 5AU<br>\
                    <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Bristol/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.8495256,-5.0243318,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4871836681b3d861:0x8ee4b22e4b9ad71f!2m2!1d-2.58791!2d51.454513!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></center></strong>',
      lat: 50.2501818,
      long: -5.1924054
    };

    var redruth = {
      info: '<strong>Redruth Train Station</strong><br>\
                    Redruth<br>Cornwall, TR15 2AB<br>\
                    <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/TR15+2AB,+Station+Rd,+Redruth/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.2428949,-5.2183829,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b1f5fb5f4a7ed:0xfa94523df7169fe6!2m2!1d-5.2258756!2d50.2332886!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818?shorturl=1" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></strong>',
      lat: 50.233210,
      long: -5.225936
    };

    var truro = {
      info: '<strong>Truro Train Station</strong><br>\r\
                    Station Road, Truro<br> Cornwall, TR1 3HH<br>\
                    <strong><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Truro,+Station+Road,+Truro,+Cornwall+TR1+3HH/Scorrier+House,+Scorrier,+Redruth+TR16+5AU/@50.2646882,-5.1661898,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b17b40079af5d:0x9752f63a0a1484f8!2m2!1d-5.0641465!2d50.2640872!1m5!1m1!1s0x486b18b9cddd326b:0x25c89b140e8bf264!2m2!1d-5.1924054!2d50.2501818?shorturl=1" target="_blank" style="color:red">Directions to The Great Estate</a></strong>',
      lat: 50.264087,
      long: -5.064146
    };

    var locations = [
      [scorrier.info, scorrier.lat, scorrier.long, 0],
      [redruth.info, redruth.lat, redruth.long, 1],
      [truro.info, truro.lat, truro.long, 2],
    ];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      scrollwheel: false,
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2501818, -5.1924054),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      createMarker(locations[i]);
    }
  }

  function createMarker(location) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      disableAutoPan: true
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(location[0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```