# google maps infowindow set always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i'm created a google maps with javascript on my html page and i have multiple markers and infowindows.

my infowindows visible when user click marker but i want to do all infowindows visible on page load.

```
var locations = [
  ['TRY 620', 36.888932, 30.683421],
  ['TRY 772', 36.872729, 30.718440],
  ['TRY 120', 36.870532, 30.640505],
  ['TRY 32', 36.854875, 30.739554],
  ['TRY 600', 36.900189, 30.632437]
];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: searchItemMap
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);

    }
  })(marker, i));
  infowindow.open(searchItemMap, marker);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show all infowindows open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824077/show-all-infowindows-open)

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps auto open infoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695257/google-maps-auto-open-infowindow)

Comment: my question is different, i want to show all infowindows default by page load. other question answers just for clicked.

Comment: The second addresses opening all the infowindows on page load.

Answer (score 1):

One option with your code would to be attach the marker's unique infowindow as a property of the marker, with the correct contents, then use `this` inside the marker click listener to reference the marker (then you don't need function closure).

```
marker._infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: locations[i][0]});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  this._infowindow.open(searchItemMap, this);
});
// open marker on load
google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/79h2v2nc/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var searchItemMap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: searchItemMap
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker._infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      this._infowindow.open(searchItemMap, this);
    });
    // open marker on load
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }
  searchItemMap.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var locations = [
  ['TRY 620', 36.888932, 30.683421],
  ['TRY 772', 36.872729, 30.718440],
  ['TRY 120', 36.870532, 30.640505],
  ['TRY 32', 36.854875, 30.739554],
  ['TRY 600', 36.900189, 30.632437]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```